# Why did Myne frame Naofumi?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

In *The Rising of the Shield Hero*, Myne chose the Shield Hero as her aid and later betrayed him for some mere 800 gold coins, that were equally divided between heroes.

I did not find any reason why she did that.

Is it because Naofumi is a Shield Hero (a degraded hero)?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to see the full anime, if you have seen it till the final episode and you still can't discover why you can read my answer

> Because Myne is royalty, she didn't betray him for a mere 800 coins, but she was trying to mock of him from the beginning, it has been showed that she is the second princess to the throne, so it is basically just making fun of the degraded hero, proof : https://shield-hero.fandom.com/wiki/Malty_S_Melromarc you can find here position as queen

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: The current airing episode is 11 so there's more to come from this Story, and I know that Myne belong to royalty and she use her royalty power to mock Naofumi but even after episode 1 she still trying to mock Naofumi in episode 4 using the spear Hero.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer it. It's not a reason why, as other royalty seems to have no problems with the Shield hero. It's just the King and Myne.

Comment: To add, I do not see how being a royalty as a proof to your statement that she 'is basically just making fun of the degraded hero'. Furthermore, that wiki page you mentioned contradicts everything in your answer. If that is speculation on your part, then please cite relevant sources/references, preferably from the light novel and anime.